# Adding missing locations on OpenStreetMap programmatically for Android application?

Tags: openstreetmap, android, missing-data

i am working on android application using osm. Many locations are not on osm that google map providing. But i need to show all missing locations on osm also.
what can i do to solve this problem? 
Can i do in this way: Get all missing location's detail from google map and then put all those locations on osm?

Comment: Almost certainly not, check out osm's rules on contributions

Answer (score 1):

No, as Ian Turton says you can't add data from Google to OSM.  You can get more information on what are suitable sources for OSM [here](http://www.openstreetmap.org/welcome) and [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Copyright#Proprietary_data).